# Request.QueryString["string"] - Is there really no simple way?

Tags: c#, url, razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been reading quite a few bits and bobs...

I just wanted to make sure that there is no way of getting the query parameter by a string with ease.

so let's say the URL IS:

```
www.example.com?sort=hi
```

can I not call

```
@SomeMethodIDoNotKnow.GetQuery("sort")
```

for example in PHP you get `$_GET["sort"]` ...

I have tried `@Request.QueryString["sort"]` but it requires an int :(

Comment: Are we talking about MVC?

Comment: Yes, sorry, added the tags.

Comment: It shouldn't require an `int` unless that `Request.QueryString` isn't the one I expect it to be.

Comment: Chris, you're right man. crappp, I had completely ignored the second overload. Cheers dude!

Comment: @JamesT: Wait... you mean you didn't actually try this before posting this question? Dude!

Comment: Unfortuantely I had, but it was throwing an error... I assumed that it was the fact it was only taking an int... but BEHOLD, another error in my code. I'm sorry everyone.. down vote the crap out of me. so so sorry. Love you all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Request.QueryString has two overloads. One takes an int, and the other takes a string. So you can do exactly what you want to do.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`@Request.QueryString["sort"]` does not require an `int`.

`QueryString` is of type `NameValueCollection` of which there is an overload that accepts the query string parameter name value as the key.

```
string fullname1 = Request.QueryString["fullname"];
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> `Item[String]`    Gets or sets the entry with the specified key in the NameValueCollection.